# Why is true? $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{a}\left[ {\frac{b}{x}} \right] = \frac{b}{a}$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

$$\begin{array}{l}a,b > 0\\\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{a}\left[ {\frac{b}{x}} \right] = \frac{b}{a}\\\end{array}
$$

I asked already a similar question, but I'm still not sure what makes it true.
As $x$ is decreasing to $0$, $x \over a$ is converging to $0$ but $\left[ {\frac{b}{x}} \right]$ is converging to $\infty$, So we left with $0*\infty$ which isn't helpful.

How can you solve it?

Comment: $0 \le \frac{x}{a} \lceil \frac{b}{x} \rceil \le \frac {x}{a} \frac{b}{x}$

Comment: Are you implying the limit is $0$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint**

Use the squeeze theorem knowing
$$\frac{b}{x}-1\le\left[ {\frac{b}{x}} \right]\le \frac{b}{x}$$

Comment: I should have know that :)

Comment: Now you know it;-)

Answer (score 2):

We have,

$\displaystyle\mathtt{\lim_{x\to\,0}\dfrac{x}{a}\left[\dfrac{b}{x}\right]}$

$\displaystyle=\mathtt{\lim_{x\to\,0}\dfrac{x}{a}\left(\dfrac{b}{x}-\left\{\dfrac{b}{x}\right\}\right)}$

$\displaystyle=\mathtt{\lim_{x\to\,0}\dfrac{x}{a}\cdot\dfrac{b}{x}-\dfrac{x}{a}\cdot\left\{\dfrac{b}{x}\right\}}$

$\displaystyle=\mathtt{\lim_{x\to\,0}\dfrac{b}{a}-\lim_{x\to\,0}\dfrac{x}{a}\cdot\left\{\dfrac{b}{x}\right\}}$

$\displaystyle=\mathtt{\dfrac{b}{a}-\lim_{x\to\,0}\dfrac{x}{a}\cdot\left\{\dfrac{b}{x}\right\}}$

The limit $\,\,\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\,0}\dfrac{x}{a}\cdot\left\{\dfrac{b}{x}\right\}=0$

because the term $\dfrac{x}{a}$ is $0$ , if we put $x=0$ and the term $\left\{\dfrac{b}{x}\right\}\in[0,1)\,\,\,\,\,\because\{y\}\in[0,1)$

So, $0\times[0,1)=0$

Hence, the required limit is $\dfrac{b}{a}$